# jQuery validation plugin not detecting blank field elements as invalid after they have been validated

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, validation

**Form validation plugin:**
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

**Test url:**
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

**How to reproduce:**
1.) Click on the name text input. Enter "12345".
2.) Tab to the next field. Enter an invalid email such as "12345@".
3.) Click on the name text input. Delete the data in the field.
4.) Click to an empty field.

Notice how the name field no longer reports incorrect data. It will be stuck like this until you refresh the page or make the email address valid. This is not the behavior I need, and I believe the spec says that this is incorrect. Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Comment: The "spec" being http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#A_few_things_to_look_for_when_playing_around_with_the_demo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a bug in the library. There is no obvious workaround.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, but when you press submit, it asks for the name again.

Comment: ...I understand that. I need realtime validation though, and this problem seems to be a violation of the specification.